# Problems reading from SDCARD with getExternalStorageDirectory(), java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/magazine/lowres/1.jpg

Tags: android, android-sdcard

i'm using the standard method for reading files stored on the sdcard:

```
public static Bitmap loadImage( String imageName ){
        File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();          
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(root+"/magazine/lowres/"+imageName+".jpg", opt);               
        return image;
    }
```

The image is on that directory, but i'm getting this excepction:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/magazine/lowres/1.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED:

Samsung Galaxy Tab has a good amount of internal flash memory. So Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() returns /mnt/sdcard/ but this is actually the internal storage. The real external storage is in /mnt/sdcard/external_sd/.

Comment: I've seen this on other devices too. Mark as correct so people don't keep answering!